# ggplot2: how to color a graph by multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am fairly certain I have seen a solution for this somewhere, but as I have been unable to find it, here is my problem.

I have some time series data identified by multiple variables, I would like to be able to graph and differentiate color using multiple variables in `ggplot2`.

Sample data:

```
date <- c("2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC",
          "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC",
          "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC")
temp <- c(80.24018,  85.88911, 104.23125,  85.13571,  91.21129, 104.88333,  97.81116,
          107.40484, 121.03958,  87.91830)
id <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
location <- c("N","S","S","N","N","S","N","S","N","S")

df <- data.frame(date,temp,id,location)
```

My attempt at graphing

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=temp,colour=factor(location), group=interaction(location,id)))
```

Using this code it is only coloring by location. I would like to the lines to be colored by location and id.

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date), temp, color = id, linetype = location)) + geom_path()`? Or `ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date), temp, color = id:location)) + geom_line()`, but that's a lot more confusing to read.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two options:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(date = c("2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC"),
                 temp = c(80.24018,  85.88911, 104.23125,  85.13571,  91.21129, 104.88333,  97.81116, 107.40484, 121.03958,  87.91830),
                 id = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
                 location = c("N","S","S","N","N","S","N","S","N","S"))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)    # parse dates to get a nicer x-axis
```

Map `id` to color and `location` to linetype:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(date, temp, color = id, linetype = location)) + geom_path()
```

[image]

...or plot all interactions as different colors:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(date, temp, color = id:location)) + geom_path()
```

[image]

Comment: The second method does not appear to work anymore. David Pritchard's solution appears to fix the issue though.

Answer (score 6):

The colon syntax didn't work for me either, but this did:

`ggplot(df, aes(date, temp, color = interaction(id, location, sep=':'))) + geom_path()`

Answer (score 3):

I want to provide another way of doing that. I don't know why but 
`color=id:location` doesn't work for me. I solved it by using `tidyr::unite`

This way I did it:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(date = c("2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC", "2016-05-01 UTC", "2016-06-01 UTC", "2016-04-01 UTC"),
                 temp = c(80.24018,  85.88911, 104.23125,  85.13571,  91.21129, 104.88333,  97.81116, 107.40484, 121.03958,  87.91830),
                 id = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
                 location = c("N","S","S","N","N","S","N","S","N","S"))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date) 

df <- tidyr::unite(df,"id_loc",id,location,remove = F)
ggplot(df,aes(date, temp, color = id_loc)) + geom_path()
```

[plot generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXNE0.png)