R ggplot add legend to graph associating custom color palette to column names
I have a dataset of multiple measurements that were taken under two different conditions. I graphed each dataset on the same graph and used a different color palette for the different conditions the data was gathered under. I've also joined all the sets of data so that they are in a single dataframe that looks like this:



device1 condition1
device2 condition1
device1 condition2
device2 condition2
n




10
20
20
40
1


30
40
60
80
2



After running the below code I ended up with the subsequent graph:
#counter = number of devices being measured
 counter <- length((merged_data) - 1) / 2 #the formula is different in my actual code but this number is equivalent

blue_shades <- scales::seq_gradient_pal("blue", "lightblue")(seq(0, 1, length.out = counter))
red_shades <- scales::seq_gradient_pal("red", "lightcoral")(seq(0, 1, length.out = counter))
      
plot_graph <- ggplot(data = merged_data)      
for (i in seq_len(counter)) {
# Blue shades for condition1, Red shades for condition2
     plot_graph <- plot_graph +
     geom_line(aes(y = .data[[names(merged_data)[i]]], x = n), color = blue_shades[i], linewidth = if (i == 1) 1.75 else 0.75) +  
     geom_line(aes(y = .data[[names(merged_data)[counter + i]]], x = n), color = red_shades[i], linewidth = if (i == 1) 1.75 else 0.75) 
}
plot_graph <- plot_graph +
    ylab("y") + 
xlab("x") 


I want to add a legend to this plot that will show the name of the column and the color that represents it on the graph, but I'm not sure how to do this. I tried moving the color field to be inside aes, as shown below, but that produced different incorrect plot (also shown below)
 plot_graph <- plot_graph +
         geom_line(aes(y = .data[[names(merged_data)[i]]], x = n, color = blue_shades[i]), linewidth = if (i == 1) 1.75 else 0.75) +  
         geom_line(aes(y = .data[[names(merged_data)[counter + i]]], x = n, color = red_shades[i]), linewidth = if (i == 1) 1.75 else 0.75)
 


Does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix this and get the proper colors and legend?
Edit: Here is a few rows of actual data that I'm working with.


Can you use dput to share some of your data? I think you are fighting against ggplot to write things in a base R way. You'll want to put your data in long format, map color to a variable, then use an appropriate color scale, but it's hard to show without some data.

Note that you can also colour by the interaction of two variables (aes(..., color = var1:var2)): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599859/ggplot2-how-to-color-a-graph-by-multiple-variables

@Axeman I added a few rows of actual data to the post

merged_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -n, names_to = "device", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = value, color = device, group = device)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(blue_shades,red_shades),
    breaks = colnames(merged_data)[1:length(merged_data) - 1]
  )



Example data:
merged_data <- tibble(
  c1_aggregate = runif(100, 75, 85), 
  d1_c1 = rnorm(100, 30, 1), 
  d2_c1 = rnorm(100, 25, 1), 
  d3_c1 = rnorm(100, 20, 1), 
  c2_aggregate = rnorm(100, 50, 0.01), 
  d1_c2 = rnorm(100, 31, .1), 
  d2_c2 = rnorm(100, 26, .1),
  d3_c2 = rnorm(100, 21, .1), 
  n = 1:100 
)

